# Replace or hide similar values in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Problem:

I am retrieving value from database where it will match the the `availabilityID` of an supervisor and examiner. However, if there is no `availabilityID` match between these two, the `availabilityID` will be 0 by default.

I have made a condition in my servlet where if both `availabilityID` is 0, I want to replace it with any number chosen by my query.

part of my servlet:

```
 for (int i=0 ; i<studentID.length ; i++){

     FreeBean free = new FreeBean();

     free = GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);

     nt SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
     int EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
     Date FreeDate = free.getFreeDate();


     out.println("<td>"+ studentID[i]+"</td>");
     out.println("<td> Hello </td>");
     out.println("<td>"+ supervisorID[i] +"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+ examinerID[i] +"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+ SVavailableID+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+ EXavailableID+"</td>");
     out.println("<td>"+ FreeDate+"</td>");
     out.println("</tr>");

     if (SVavailableID ==0 && EXavailableID ==0 )
     {

        free= GenerateScheduleDAO.getOtherFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);

        int otherSVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
        int otherEXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();

        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>"+ studentID[i]+"</td>");
        out.println("<td> Hello </td>");
        out.println("<td>"+ supervisorID[i] +"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+ examinerID[i] +"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+ otherSVavailableID+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+ otherEXavailableID+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+ FreeDate+"</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");

     }

}// student loop
```

I am aware my result turns out to be like this :

```
Student Name | Project Title  | Supervisor Name |  Examiner Name |    Presentation 1 | Presentation 2 |   Date

     abc          1111               tan               tin               0                    0          1/1/16
     abc          1111               tan               tin               12                  12         1/1/16
```

The first row shows, the `availabilityID` for both supervisor and examiner are 0. Thus, it will execute the IF statement and find another possible `availabilityID` for them. As a result, it will duplicate the row where one consist of 0 and one consist of new value.

How can I REPLACE the row with both 0 with new value. Or AT LEAST, hide the row with both `availabilityID` =0 and only display with the new value retrieved. Is there any efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is to make certain that you execute one and only one flow of logic.  Using an `if` statement in the right place will let you achieve that.

```
for (int i=0; i < studentID.length; i++) {
    FreeBean free = new FreeBean();
    free = GenerateScheduleDAO.getFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);

    int SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
    int EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
    Date FreeDate = free.getFreeDate();

    // handle the edge case here
    if (SVavailableID == 0 && EXavailableID == 0) {
        free = GenerateScheduleDAO.getOtherFree(supervisorID[i],examinerID[i]);

        SVavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
        EXavailableID = free.getAvailableID();
    }

    // now print out each record only one time
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>"+ studentID[i]+"</td>");
    out.println("<td> Hello </td>");
    out.println("<td>"+ supervisorID[i] +"</td>");
    out.println("<td>"+ examinerID[i] +"</td>");
    out.println("<td>"+ SVavailableID+"</td>");
    out.println("<td>"+ EXavailableID+"</td>");
    out.println("<td>"+ FreeDate+"</td>");
    out.println("</tr>");
}
```

One other way to approach your problem would be to let the SQL query handle the double zero value for you.